# Retrieve a map stored in a different class

Tags: java, dictionary

Is it possible to retrieve a map stored in a different class?
For eg:

I have Class A in which I have the below map:

```
Map<String,List<Names>> map=new HashMap<String,List<Names>>();
map.put("Details", Names);
```

Is it possible to retrieve the map in Class B?

Comment: Please read a tutorial on classes and objects. The fact that it is a `Map` makes no difference.

Comment: Yes. Please be more specific and we can give you a more specific answer. If you are working through a text or tutorial and your question is to help understand questions it has raised, please include a reference to what you're reading. If you are not working through a text or tutorial, please consider doing so.

Comment: I am sorry. I have created a class A and a map which consists of collections.                                        Map<String,List<Names>> map=new HashMap<String,List<Names>>();
map.put("Details", Names); Now I want to access the created map in Class B to retrieve the values from Class A. My requirement is not to retrieve the map in Class A. Can I retrieve the map with key "Details" in Class B?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to retrieve *[or retrieve from]* the map in Class B?

Yes it is.  And there are a variety of ways to do it.  For example:

- You could make the Map variable `public` (almost certainly a bad idea!)
- You could implement a `public` getter that returns the Map (probably not a good idea ...)
- You could implement a `public` getter that returned a read-only wrapper for the (private) Map.
- You could implement a `public` method that looks up an entry in the (private) Map.

But it is not necessarily a *good thing* to do these things.  One of the principles of Object Oriented Programming is that a class should encapsulate its state.  If your class B can access a map that is (for the sake of argument) internal to your class A, then the encapsulation is weakened or broken in the process.  (Now, it might be appropriate to have loose encapsulation ... but you need to understand the issues and think through the consequence for your particular circumstances.)

What I'm saying is that you most likely need to find / read a tutorial (or text book) on OO programming to help you understand whether what you are trying to do is the right thing to do.